Confluence API integration on wordpress site
We're trying to fetch Confluence page content on a WordPress site using the Confluence API. The API returns a response when tested via Postman, but it doesn't work on the WordPress page.
I've created a custom plugin and am using a shortcode on the WordPress page.
I am getting "No content found for this page" error on page.
Below is the plugin code:
    <?php

function get_confluence_page_content($page_id) {
    $confluence_url = 'https://project.atlassian.com/project/rest/api/content/' . $page_id;
    $username = 'test@myemail.com';
    $api_token = '23fgg345676gdfh4567586543243546567ijhgfzju764667ijhgsawretytutiuyh';
    $url = $confluence_url;

    // Setup the request headers for Basic Authentication
    $auth = base64_encode($username . ':' . $api_token);
    $args = array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'headers' => array(
            'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . $auth,
            'Accept' => 'application/json',
        ),
        // Bypass SSL certificate verification
        'sslverify' => false,  // Disable SSL verification
    );

    // Make the API call
    $response = wp_remote_get($url, $args);

    // Log response for debugging
    if (is_wp_error($response)) {
        error_log('Error fetching Confluence page: ' . $response->get_error_message());
        return 'Error fetching content';
    }

    // Parse the response
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $data = json_decode($body, true);

    // Log the raw response
    error_log('Confluence API response: ' . print_r($data, true));

    // Check if we have the content
    if (isset($data['body']['storage']['value'])) {
        return $data['body']['storage']['value'];
    } else {
        return 'No content found for this page.';
    }
}

function display_confluence_content($atts) {
    // Retrieve the Confluence page content by passing the page ID
    $atts = shortcode_atts(array('id' => ''), $atts);
    if (!$atts['id']) {
        return 'Page ID is required.';
    }

    $page_content = get_confluence_page_content($atts['id']);
    return $page_content;
}

add_shortcode('confluence_page', 'display_confluence_content');
?>

This is the shortcode - [confluence_page id="12345677"]

And what was the API response written to your error log? (In case that was NULL, also check on what $body contained.)
